# Adding placeholders to the user login block's username and password input fields

Tags: theming, 8

**Task**

I'm trying to add the placeholder attribute to the username and password input fields of the user login block.

**Problem**

When I have twig debug on, the only twig file overrides list are the following.

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
* input--textfield.html.twig
x input.html.twig
-->
```

I don't want to use either of these twig files as it would apply to every input or every textfield.

**Caveat**

I'm wanting to accomplish this from within my theme not a custom module. Which I'm not sure is able to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In twig it's difficult to target a specific input field. You can do this more efficient in a form alter hook, which you can use in themes too:

**mytheme.theme**

```
function mytheme_form_user_login_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form['name']['#placeholder'] = t('placeholder for username');
}
```

Comment: Can you update your answer to utilize t() please? Thank you for the help!

Comment: added t() function.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login_form' ) {
    // Add placeholders.
    $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Email/Mobile Number');
    $form['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Password');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

clean solution

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_html().
 */
function THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $current_path = \Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
  $path_alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
  $path_alias = ltrim($path_alias, '/');
  $variables['attributes']['class'][] = 'path-' . \Drupal\Component\Utility\Html::cleanCssIdentifier($path_alias);
}
```